# Alamofire : Type of expression is ambiguous in .GET

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to make a simple download using the Alamofire framework. Just when I pasted a code for download into my Project (swift 2), I get this error in this Alamofire code:

```
Alamofire.download(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/stream/100", destination: destination)
            .progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
                print(totalBytesRead)

                // This closure is NOT called on the main queue for performance
                // reasons. To update your ui, dispatch to the main queue.
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    print("Total bytes read on main queue: \(totalBytesRead)")
                }
            }
            .response { _, _, _, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Failed with error: \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("Downloaded file successfully")
                }
        }
```

at .GET request 
I've already tried to fix it by :

not .GET but Alamofire.Method.GET , and no success...

Can someone help please ?

Comment: Can you mentioned the whole error here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the wrong path directory, the problem is that when I want to use my own path to downloaded file, I have to use it like this:

```
Alamofire.download(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/stream/100") { temporaryURL, response in
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let directoryURL = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    let pathComponent = response.suggestedFilename

    return directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent!)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the Alamofire pod?

If so, make sure you've added `import Alamofire` to the top of your file.

Comment: I didn't installed Alamofire by pod file. But it's imported to the project correctly.